# Responsive Navigation Hamburger Menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make my navigation responsive but when i tried to resize my window, my hamburger doesn't allow the dropdown function to work. I took both the navigation and responsive hamburger online so is there somewhere that might be overwriting the hamburger ?

This is my HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p>LEGEND</p>
    <div class= "hamburger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button>
  <a href="#">
  <h4 style="color: #f5f5f5">PLAY DIVINE</h4>
  </a>
  </button>
</header>
```

This is my css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #12171c;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 15px;
}
a, button {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #b7b9bb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button {
    background: #967526;
    border: 2px solid #ffce1f;
    padding: 9px 25px;
}
.header-pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.hamburger {
    display: none;
}
```

This is my css when it's responsive

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
.hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger .line {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fefefe;
    margin: 6px 0;
}
.nav-bar {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #11101b;
    transition: 0.2s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-bar.active {
    height: 450px;
}
.nav-bar ul {
    display: block;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.nav-bar.active ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav-bar ul li a {
    margin-botton: 12px;
}
}
```

This is my javascript

```
<script>
 hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
 hamburger.onClick = function() {
  navBar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
  navbar.classList.toggle("active");
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I revised the solution so that the 2 blocks are for:

1. In small screen but `active` is not on
2. In small screen and `active` is on

This separation protects the style from broken when transition happen as `active` toggles.

More styles can be added to the first block to define how this list should look like, such as making it display the list in column.

Example:

```
.nav-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-bar.active ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Original**

This is because your JS code has some syntax error. Here is what to do:

1. Use `const` to declare `hamburger` and `navbar`.
2. Call `addEventListener` on `hamburger` to add the function for toggling class of `navbar`

Follow the below example to revise your code, or visit a live demo of it fixed here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/john-zhuangzhuang-li/pen/ExRXNGq)

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => navbar.classList.toggle("active"));
```

Hope this solution will help.

Comment: thanks it's working now, but now for some reason the list is side by side instead of up and down

Comment: @JeremyChan Any chance you can specify what happened now and what would be the desired result?

Comment: the dropdown is working now but the items inside are side by side each other instead of columns

Comment: @JeremyChan Perhaps we are looking at 2 version of codes because in your posted code, there is a `.nav-bar.active ul {display: none; }` which makes the list disappear when `active`, so no item is displaying at all for me. Is there another list in a drop down that is not posted?

Comment: yes the .nav-bar.active ul {display: none;} are supposed to be .nav-bar.active ul {opacity: 1} i've made the changes in the original question. That was my bad on that.

Comment: @JeremyChan I see no worries, I added some advice in the answer about where to add styles for styling this list when `active` is on. Hope it helps and if it does, please accept the answer so this post is complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has nothing wrong, just few typos in your JavaScript:

1. You have `onClick` instead of `onclick`
2. `navbar` instead of `navBar` at `navbar.classList.toggle("active")`

**Corrected version**

```
<script>
  hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  hamburger.onclick = function() {
    navBar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
    navBar.classList.toggle("active");
  }
</script>
```

**Extra** (*Change `display: block;` to `display: grid;` in `.nav-bar ul` selector in CSS media query to display dropdown in vertical list*)

```
.nav-bar ul {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```js
hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.onclick = function() {
  navBar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
  navBar.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #12171c;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

a,
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #b7b9bb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background: #967526;
  border: 2px solid #ffce1f;
  padding: 9px 25px;
}

.header-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .hamburger .line {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fefefe;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  .nav-bar {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #11101b;
    transition: 0.2s;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav-bar.active {
    height: 450px;
  }
  .nav-bar ul {
    display: grid;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-bar.active ul {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav-bar ul li a {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p>LEGEND</p>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button>
    <a href="#">
      <h4 style="color: #f5f5f5">PLAY DIVINE</h4>
    </a>
  </button>
</header>
```

---

#### Better Solution

Quote from MDN Web Docs, as in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener):

> The recommended mechanism for adding event handlers in web pages is the `addEventListener()` method

You may use `addEventListener()` to achieve the same result:

```
<script>
  hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navBar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
    navBar.classList.toggle("active");
  });
</script>
```

```js
hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navBar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
  navBar.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #12171c;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

a,
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #b7b9bb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background: #967526;
  border: 2px solid #ffce1f;
  padding: 9px 25px;
}

.header-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .hamburger .line {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fefefe;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  .nav-bar {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #11101b;
    transition: 0.2s;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav-bar.active {
    height: 450px;
  }
  .nav-bar ul {
    display: grid;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-bar.active ul {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav-bar ul li a {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p>LEGEND</p>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button>
    <a href="#">
      <h4 style="color: #f5f5f5">PLAY DIVINE</h4>
    </a>
  </button>
</header>
```

---

#### Alternate Solution

For readers who are more familiar to `add()` / `remove()`, here's some alternatives:

```
<script>
  hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navBar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
    if (navBar.classList.contains("active")) {
      navBar.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      navBar.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
</script>
```

```js
hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navBar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
  if (navBar.classList.contains("active")) {
    navBar.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
    navBar.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #12171c;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

a,
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #b7b9bb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background: #967526;
  border: 2px solid #ffce1f;
  padding: 9px 25px;
}

.header-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .hamburger .line {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fefefe;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  .nav-bar {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #11101b;
    transition: 0.2s;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav-bar.active {
    height: 450px;
  }
  .nav-bar ul {
    display: grid;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-bar.active ul {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav-bar ul li a {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p>LEGEND</p>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button>
    <a href="#">
      <h4 style="color: #f5f5f5">PLAY DIVINE</h4>
    </a>
  </button>
</header>
```

---